# Getting error 'Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties"'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am following Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial and while deploying my first app, I am getting the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":

  In Gemfile:

    rails (= 4.0.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (= 4.0.0) x86-mingw32

    sass-rails (= 4.0.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (4.0.1.rc3)
```

My Gemfile looks like the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails',   '4.0.0'

gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'

gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'

gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.

  gem 'sdoc', require: false

end
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: What version of rubygems are you using? `gem -v`

Comment: @NickM: That recommends installing an RC version of Devise, which is incorrect. The Gemfile in the question above does not even include Devise.

Comment: @RyanBigg I am following tutorial step by step and I dont see 'Devise' being mentioned any where.

Comment: I have railties installed, C:\rubyexample\first_app>gem list railties

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

railties (4.0.0, 3.2.13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reinstall the railties gem again then

```
gem install railties
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle update`

If that doesn't work, delete Gemfile.lock and run

```
bundle install.
```

And restart server